# Reasons to install X Windows on a Linux server

Tags: linux, x11

Is there any advantage to installing X on a server, eg a db or web server? I'm thinking it would just add mem/cpu overhead. Is it more normal not to install it on a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation will not result in memory or cpu overhead. Installation only will use up disc space.

However if you ever find yourself at the display connected to the machine and are forced to use a commandline/text only version of a utility for which task you are more familiar with a graphical tool, you can always startup  X and "waste" the cpu/mem for that task and then shut it down.

E.g. some find GUI versions of of the package managers more intuitive then their text-only interactive variants (curses based) and/or commandline versions. My impression the last few years is that if all three exist, the GUI and commandline versions have gotten more development attention than the curses based version.

But if you are not at the "console" (assuming it supports a GUI) and you normally use `ssh` from a workstation running X, then you should be able to use those GUI based tools from that workstation, without installing X on the server. Those tools are X clients and their libraries are normally installed. E.g. if you install Firefox on your server, but not X, you can run this, started from the server, displayed using the X Window System on your workstation.

Just be aware that quite a lot of X installs come with additional desktop environments and that, when installed, they usually start automatically. You can however switch off this automatic start, details depending on your distribution.

Comment: Yeah most of the ones I've seen start automatically, with KDE.

Comment: @MartinRennix As I indicated, hat is not necessary. And I hope the **disc space** taken by the X related packages is not your limiting factor.

Answer (score 0):

For the server tasks, you don't need X server at all. All services work fine without GUI. For remote connection, you can use ssh. Actually, usage of CLI ususally gives you more facilities to manage server than GUI does.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen quite a few servers with X installed and I was wondering why. I guess it might make life easier for some simple tasks for junior admins? Eg LVM management via GUI instead of CLI.

Comment: People should learn to use the CLI version of such tools ASAP, in the long term it will save time and trouble, e.g. when you're on the road and only have ssh access to fix a problem.

Comment: @Martin I don't think that it will make work easier. You'll just end up using terminal in X server. But it could be useful if you need to google someting (but you can use console browsers like lynx or links and there's man, so...)